# How protect .NET Web API with password without database and identity

Tags: c#, .net, rest, security, asp.net-web-api

Given that in future I will implement a gateway with integrated security, I need a fast and simple way to protect a .NET 6 web service: its goal is to be an interface to search in a lucene.net index.

I have some particularity:

- The web service is in a corporate company and external authority like Azure, AWS or Auth0 is not an option
- I don't have any database or persistence layer
- I don't have to manage users list or profile, if caller service has the correct password or token should be able to use all my API without any registration

Now we have an older application with this logic:

- every action has user and password parameters
- user and password are stored in config file
- every call manually check for user and password with config file

I am wondering if there is a better way but just as simple?

I would like to not have to send password in every call and having to write an if in every action

Thanks

Comment: *just as simple?* - why not do some well trodden JWT plus middleware approach - it's even simpler

Comment: Like Caius said, use JWT or bearer tokens. Or simply put a custom header (key/value) that only the users know of and read it in middleware

Comment: ok, so i can add jwt and check credential against config instead of database and forget about having user model, claims and so on? i found only example that match jwt and some sort of user class

Comment: https://bytelanguage.net/2021/07/30/net-6-jwt-authentication-in-minimal-web-api/

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/12/14/net-6-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

can be good starting point?

Comment: other idea:  https://jolicode.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-jwt

Comment: Use basic auth can help here eventually [here](https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/how-to-add-basic-authentication-to-asp-net-core-application#:~:text=Basic%20Authentication%20works%20by%20adding,password%20are%20encoded%20using%20Base64.)

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach could be writing a simple middleware which checks if the  provided bearer token is the same as the one you stored in appsettings.json.

```
public class BearerAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public BearerAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        
        if (!context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var
                bearerTokenRequest))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Bearer token not found");
            return;
        }

        var appSettings = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var bearerToken = "Bearer "+ appSettings.GetValue<string>("bearerToken");
        if (bearerToken != bearerTokenRequest)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid bearer token");
            return;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}



public class BearerAuthenticationPipeline
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<BearerAuthenticationMiddleware>();
    }
}


[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(BearerAuthenticationPipeline))]

public class MyApiController : ControllerBase
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: interesting, iam going to try it